# Make Feature Layer / Select / Select Layer By Attribute "Get Unique Values" grayed out in ArcMap ModelBuilder [10.8.1]

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, extract, unique-value, select-by-expression

I'm trying to extract road segments from a feature class through ModelBuilder in ArcMap 10.8.1 based on attribute queries, but the "Get Unique Values" button does not pull up a list of values when I click on it. Of the three tools that I have tried for this (Make Feature Layer, Select, Select Layer By Attribute) they all produce the same non-result.

Below is a screenshot that shows the tools I've used leading up to the selection step, and what happens when I try to "Get Unique Values" from these various tools. I know that sometimes ModelBuilder is fussy about which selection tool is used based on whether the data is a feature class or feature layer.

Can someone tell me what is happening and how to make it work?

[image]

Cross-posting from [GeoNet](https://community.esri.com/thread/259747-make-feature-layer-select-select-layer-by-attribute-get-unique-values-grayed-out-in-modelbuilder-1081) to try to reach as many people as possible!

---

UPDATE

I should mention that if I try to manually type a query into the main Make Feature Layer, Select, or Select Layer By Attribute tool, it won't verify.

Still haven't figured out the initial problem, but I did find a workaround by inserting a Calculator Expression from the Create Variable option and linking it to the tool. Hopefully this is helpful!

Comment: Can you not simply type the value in? I know this may not give you the user experience you desire but you can manually complete the expression and as this only needs to be done once for you model, it's no effort at all.

Comment: No, the model breaks if I type in the value.